# How can I use deep link with animation in Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, deeplink

I'd like to navigate to last page Fragment when restart application.
Ex) MainFragment > UserListFragment > **UserDetailFragment**
Using the NavDeepLinkBuilder I created deep link because I need create deep link dynamically.

```
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(requireContext())
        .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
        .setDestination(R.id.userDetailFragment)
        .createPendingIntent();
pendingIntent.send();
```

It's works as expected but there is no animation.
If I using deeplink by Uri, I might be able to use NavController#navigate(Uri, NavOptions).

Is there a way to use animation with NavDeepLinkBuilder?

Sorry for my bad English.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an action for the navigation?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Yes I do. When using NavController#navigate, it is animated. however, I can't using it.

Comment: But if you use `setGraph` and then send the id of the graph that contains the deep-link can't you put animation inside of it?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Adding <deepLink> to the NavGraph and using NavController#navigate(Uri, NavOptions) made the animation run.  
However, there is no stack...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `navigate` you can add another parameter as `NavOptions`

```
public void navigate(@NonNull Uri deepLink, @Nullable NavOptions navOptions) {
    navigate(deepLink, navOptions, null);
}
```

And then create the `NavOptions` programmatically as

```
val navOptions =
    NavOptions.Builder()
        .setPopUpTo(
            R.id.nav_graph_main,
            false
        )
        .setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_right)
        .setExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_left)
        .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_left)
        .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_right)
        .build()
```

Or also you can create the action in the `xml` as follows

```
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_notes_to_noteDetail"
            app:destination="@id/noteDetailFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_slide_down"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_slide_down"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/pop_enter_slide_up"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/pop_exit_slide_up" />
```

For more information, you can check this [navigation-architecture-component](https://proandroiddev.com/navigation-architecture-component-for-the-rest-of-us-faafa890e5)

Comment: Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: They are asking about navigation with deep links using `NavDeepLinkBuilder`, not a normal navigation.